# LSTM input and output for sentiment analysis

Tags: neural-network, lstm, rnn, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm studying this LSTM network:
https://www.kaggle.com/paoloripamonti/twitter-sentiment-analysis

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()
```

I understand the input part of the embedding layer. Each word get's a unique vector that represents the meaning of the word.

The drop out will deactivate neurons.
So the input for the LSTM model is the vocabulary where each token is represented by a vector.

I understand the workflow in an LSTM model. But what exactly does it do with the input? Give it a score by learning?
And what is the output of the lstm?

Here is the summary:

[image]

Comment: Is the question here "How does an LSTM work?" or is the question specific to this use case?

Comment: Specific for this case. I know how a LSTM works (the gates, nodes etc). But I wonder what happens with my dataset and what the output is of the LSTM. Is it a 2D vector for each word?

Comment: so the input are vectors that represents tokens. The output is a vector with represents the sentiment score? Or not?

Answer (score 1):

Here it looks like the model takes in sequences of words, which are turned into embeddings, which are then put into the LSTM layer. The output of the LSTM layer is a 100 (because this is what is specified in the model) dimensional vector. This 100 dimensional vector is then put into a Dense layer outputting a 1-dimensional object, which I am assuming is some sort of prediction. Does this help? I feel like I may be missing the question.

Comment: Did did help, thanks! What i'm still not understand. That's how the model is trained. So each word/token in the corpus get's a score. But how does the model predicts a random sentence with that corpus?

Comment: I'd have to dig into the code, but it's likely training on entire comments, not just words/tokens.

Comment: Where does that happen in the code? thank you

Comment: the output vector of the LSTM is 100 dim. Is this the output then for every token that represents the score for that token?

Comment: If you look for `x_train` in the code, you'll see where the x variable is created as a sequence of indicies using keras `tokenizer.texts_to_sequences` and `pad_sequences`. The output will be for every sequence of tokens (tweets), not individual tokens.

Comment: so while training the model, full tweets are used as a token to determine the score and not word by word?

Comment: this doesn't apply to the embedding phase?

Comment: So during the training phase, tweets are considered as a whole and is a group of tweets (batch) given as input for the model? What does the model do? What will it learn from it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't want to extend the discussion too much in these comments, but it looks like the embeddings are separately learned via a word2vec model and the embedding layer is frozen during training. The training phase reads in tweets and learns LSTM layer parameters based on the sequence of word embeddings in each tweet, and then guesses the sentiment based on the 100 dim output of the LSTM model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93110/discussion-between-belgiums-and-andy-m).